# Openshift Node JS cacheing with SFTP

Tags: node.js, caching, openshift, sftp

When installing the Node cartidge on openshift, if I make changes to my files and push the repo, everything works as it should, but if I SFTP and edit a file then the system continues to serve the cached content until I push the repo again (which may not have my SFTP changes of course)

with the PHP cartridge there is an environment variable via rhc>>
$OPENSHIFT_PHP_APC_ENABLED=true/false

when set to false, it disables this behavior and I can essentially live edit over sftp - love it...how can I produce similar results with nodejs cart?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_guide.html

> 12.4. Development Mode
>   When you push your code changes to OpenShift, if you want dynamic reloading of your javascript files in "development" mode, you can either use the hot_deploy marker or add the following to package.json:
>
> "scripts": { "start": "supervisor /relative-path-from-repo-to/server.js" },
>   This will run Node.JS with Supervisor.
>
> The hot_deploy marker is restricted to the supervisor only. Using the use_npm marker, your application will always do a full restart.